# How to change the language of the page based on select menu?

Tags: laravel

I have a select menu on the footer that has 5 languages and I would like to when the user select a language the site text translate to that language. Do you know how that can be achieved with laravel? If there is some package or something to achieve that?

```
<div class="col-6 col-lg-3 pt-4 pb-4">
  <div class="footer-list">
    <h3>Language</h3>
    <form>
      <select class="form-control font-weight-normal text-gray" id="exampleFormControlSelect1">
        <option selected class="selected">Português</option>
        <option>Geram</option>
        <option >English</option>
        <option>...</option>
      </select>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi Adam! StackOverflow actually recommends not asking for library recommendations. Laravel's community is a great place to ask for recommendations - check out [Laracasts](https://laracasts.com/), the [Slack chat](https://larachat.co/), etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using **mcamara's** [Laravel Localization package](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization). Check their [docs](https://github.com/mcamara/laravel-localization#installation) for detail implementation. It's a very user friendly & easy to go package with all the required options.